# In R, can we compare rows partitioned by a column to return a similarity score?

Tags: r

Here's a sample of my dataset.

```
df <- data.frame("TITLE" = c("GOOGLE", "GOOGLE INC.", "GOOGLE LLC"), "ADDRESS" = c("123 ABC DR", "123 ABC DR", "123 ABC DR")
```

I'd like see a new column called SIMILARITY_SCORE which would calculate how close/dissimilar the rows in the column TITLE are when partitioned by the column ADDRESS. Higher the match, the SIMILARITY_SCORE should show values closer to 1. Lower the match, the SIMILARITY_SCORE should show values closer to 0.

I have compared data between columns but since this relates to comparing data between rows, I am not sure if there's a specific function available in R for this purpose. Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for the ```stringdist``` package

Comment: What do you mean by "partitioned by the ADRESS column"?

Comment: @mark_1985 Wouldn't this be asking for similarity measures calculated within grouping of equivalent addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start using `adist`

```
# dist by group
dat <- aggregate( TITLE ~ ADDRESS, df1, function(x) 1 - adist(x) / nchar(x), simplify=F )
#     ADDRESS
#1 123 ABC DR
#                                                                                              #TITLE
#1 1.0000000, 0.5454545, 0.6000000, 0.1666667, 1.0000000, 0.7000000, 0.3333333, 0.7272727, 1.0000000

# output the line as named data frame
lin <- setNames( data.frame( dat$TITLE[[1]] ), df1$TITLE )
rownames(lin) <- df1$TITLE
lin
#               GOOGLE GOOGLE INC. GOOGLE LLC
#GOOGLE      1.0000000   0.1666667  0.3333333
#GOOGLE INC. 0.5454545   1.0000000  0.7272727
#GOOGLE LLC  0.6000000   0.7000000  1.0000000
```